# Firebase Hosting and Angular5 flex-layout

Tags: firebase, angular5, firebase-hosting, angular-flex-layout

I'm following some instructions from https://github.com/stanleyeosakul/angular-universal-firebase to get my site hosted with firebase. When I run firebase deploy, everything goes fine untill the last step. That's where I get the following error:

```
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: TypeError: _angular_core.OpaqueToken is not a 
constructor
at /user_code/node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/bundles/flex-
layout.umd.js:615:19
at value (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/bundles/flex-
layout.umd.js:2:68)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/@angular/flex-
layout/bundles/flex-layout.umd.js:5:2)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Can anyone help me with this error? Is it even possible now to use flex-layout on firebase hosting? I've been trying it allday long and it's just frustrating.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out myself. In the package.json file I've changed "@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.12" to "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.12" so don't use the ^